# Number of elementary shuffling operations to produce deck with no $k$ cards in same order?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

The requirement for "suitably shuffled" is that no $k$ cards appear in same order in $D$ and $D'$.

Elementary shuffling operations are defined, very simply, as :

1. Interleaving. Split deck in exactly two, parts $D_{top}$, $D_{bottom}$, and place each card of $D_{bottom}$ in between cards of $D_{top}$.
2. Cutting. Select a consecutive interval of cards $D_{cut}$, from $c_{start}$ to $c_{end}$ inclusive, (which can be from the middle of the deck) of some length less than |$D$|, and place it either on the top, or the bottom. Defined by 3-tuple (  $c_{start}$, $c_{end}$, $top$ or $bottom$ ) 
   (**Aside**: there also exists an Identity. One identity operation is to select any cut from the top, and place it back on the top. ( 0, $c_{end}$, $top$ ). Which can be ignored for shuffling.)

**How many such elementary shuffling operations are required to ensure the number of cards in the same order for both decks is at most $k$?, with $k$ not less than 8**

Comment: I don't see a question (assuming that the question is not intended to be "who shuffled this deck?" :-)

Comment: Much better, but "such" doesn't make any sense -- you haven't introduced any at that point. Also, if you're looking for the minimal number of operations, you can eliminate the identity, since it merely makes a sequence of operations longer without changing the result.

Comment: Well, I'd say the "this" is now rather difficult to parse because the criterion is so far above, but perhaps that's getting too nit-picking. More importantly, what do you mean by "expected" and "on average"? I don't see any random element in the setup. In case you're thinking of the intial state of the deck as a random element, note that the fixed points of a shuffling procedure don't depend on the identity of the cards being shuffled.

Comment: Also, I think you should define more explicitly what you mean by fixed points of ordered but not necessarily consecutive subsequences of equal length. My interpretation of that description would be that you pick any $k$ cards from both decks (unshuffled and shuffled), preserving their order, and then count the number of matches between the two resulting ordered $k$-tuples of cards. If this is what you have in mind, note that it's unnecessarily complicated; you could equivalently demand just that no set of $k$ cards appear in the same order in both decks.

Comment: The question is now much more concise and easier to understand. Now you just have to remove the vestiges of the fixed points in the last paragraph :-)

Comment: Thanks @Joriki ! I may be learning.

Comment: Note that a deck of $52$ cards, after shuffling, is bound to have some subset of $8$ cards in the same relative order as they were in before shuffling.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, it is? I don't see why. What is so special about 8?

Comment: If you have a sequence of $m^2+1$ or more numbers, you are bound to have a monotone subsequence of length $m+1$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erdős–Szekeres_theorem

Comment: Cool theorem, thanks (Does that have any relation to primes in arithmetic progression?). I believe the m+1, but why should the two sequences that are monotone, be the same ? The first deck could have a Clubs2-9 sequence, and the second deck could have a Hearts2-9 sequence -- what am I missing?

Comment: Cris, if you want to be sure that I see a comment, you have to use @Gerry. Now, take your first deck, and number the cards $1$ to $52$. Then shuffle. The shuffled deck will have a monotone subsequence of length (at least) $8$, monotone with respect to the ordering you imposed on the original deck by numbering the cards.

Comment: @GerryMyerson got it. Thanks Gerry, that made it clear.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: The meaning of "monotone" in the theorem is "either increasing or decreasing", which translates into "either in the same order or in the opposite order". However the question only considers the same order; reversing the order of the cards would make it "suitably shuffled". That may not be very reasonable for practical purposes, but I see no way to read the question differently.

Comment: @Marc, you're probably right. So, now what do we do?

Comment: @GerryMyerson -- we could shuffle it again. It would be unlikely that that sequence would persist. But I wonder, would a sequence from before the two shuffles still be present? And if so, wouldn't there be some weird consequences, since, after some large finite number of shuffles, the original order would be covered by 7 of these disjoint 'preserved orders'. I wonder how many shuffles it would take, such that, from all the monotone sequences found after each shuffle, the 7 disjoint covering sequences had appeared.